# why do i get TypeError: must be str, not builtin_function_or_method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, methods, traceback, built-in

I've been given a task to present the current time, and a given future time.
the user inputs the number of additional minutes he desires, and then i need to show that exact time.

I've tried the below:

```
import time


hours = int(time.strftime('%H:%M')[0:2])
minutes = int(time.strftime('%H:%M')[3:5])


def newminutes(minutes,adding):
    if minutes + adding >=60:
        return minutes + adding - 60
    else:
        return minutes + adding

def newhours(hours, minutes, adding):
    if minutes + adding >=60:
        newhour = hours + adding//60 + 1     
    else:
        newhour =  hours + adding //60
        if newhour >= 24:
            return newhour - 24
         else:
            return newhour

usersays = input("insert additional minutes: ")
usersay = int(usersays)
finalhours = newhours(hours,minutes,usersay)
finalminutes = newminutes(minutes,usersay)

print("Current Time: " +time.strftime + "\n" +
      "Future Time: "+ str(finalhours) + ":" + str(finalminutes))
```

After inputting the number of minutes, the output i get is always:

> **Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Python projects\Ex2\test2.py", line 29, in 
>       +":" + str(newminutes(minutes,usersay)))
>   TypeError: must be str, not builtin_function_or_method**

I've been trying to fix this for hours with no sucess, please explain me where have i gone wrong. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `time.strftime` is a function and you try to concatenate it with a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception you get is because you are trying to use string concatenation with a builtin function:

```
print("Current Time: " +time.strftime + "\n" +
      "Future Time: "+ str(finalhours) + ":" + str(finalminutes))
```

time.strftime is a function.

```
>>> time.strftime
<built-in function strftime>
```

You need to call it so it returns a string.
Try replacing it with the following, which returns a string object:

```
time.strftime("%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S")
'Apr 05 2018 10:57:48'
```

Comment: Thank you very much Vinny! The error stopped appearing :)

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from adding a string to a function. See [Vinnys answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49668208/7505395) for details.

Your code can be simplified **a lot** by using `datetime.time` and outputting the object correctly formatted by supplying [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) to format the time correctly:

```
import datetime

usersays = input("insert additional minutes: ")
usersay = int(usersays)

now = datetime.datetime.now()  
then = now + datetime.timedelta(minutes = usersay)  # a delta that can be added to time()

# simply format the output correctly
print(f'Current Time: {now.time():%H:%M}\n' + \
      f'Future Time:  {then.time():%H:%M}')
```

You do not need to implement all the *time-to-string-to-slice-to-numbers-to-add-minutes-maybe-adding-to-hour-if-needed* that way - you simply use the `timedelta()` object to add to a time.